# Custom Icons with Ionic 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I recently updated from Ionic 4 to Ionic 5.
With Ionic 5 the icons received an update too. Apparently however also the mechanism loading the icons changed.

In Ionic 4 it was possible to add custom icons like this: [Ionic 4: Custom Icons Made Simple](https://medium.com/@JordanBenge/how-to-create-custom-ionic-4-icons-af80cc6cc148)

Add e.g.
`ios-my-custom-icon.svg` and `md-my-custom-icon.svg`
in an `icon` folder in the `assets`. Then it was necessary to reference them in the `angular.json` like:

```js
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*.svg",
    "input": "src/assets/icon",
    "output": "./svg"
  }
]
```

and one could finally call them like the other ion-icons in html:

```html
<ion-icon name="my-custom-icon"></ion-icon>
```

However this does not work in ionic 5 anymore.
Does someone know, how we can now implement custom icons in ionic 5?

**EDIT**:
I realised it is still possible to call them through the src attribute like

```html
<ion-icon src="assets/icon/md-my-custom-icon.svg"></ion-icon>
```

However that is not convenient like using the name attribute. Any chance we have some equivalent to the above?

Comment: Having exactly same issue, this used to work with Ionic 4, also problem with using "src" attribute is that icons won't appear on IoS version of the application in my case.

Comment: Exerlol have you done an absolute url starting with `/`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the `md-` from the icon name.

For example, your icon is `md-my-custom-icon.svg`

Change to `my-custom-icon.svg`. After that the custom icons will work again on ionic 5

### Cheers

**UPDATE**

I had to put the `md-` back on the icon name and actually add the `md-` to the ion icon tag as below. This way it uses my custom icon and not the default one.

`<ion-icon name="md-my-custom-icon"></ion-icon>`

Comment: You are right, this works now. They must have changed it in a newer ionic version, because I tried the same before and it didn't. We have to remove the .svg though in order to make it work. Maybe you can edit this in your answer. Thanks mate.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am glad it worked for you...mine still works with the .svg , so I'm not sure what's going on, I will keep an eye on it, thanks for the tip. Cheers!

Comment: I did the same but it says file not found. Can you mention where you removed the .svg?

Answer (score 7):

You could always just use `[]` and then provide a variable if you prefer:

```
const myCustomIcon = "/assets/icons/custom.svg";
```

And in the markup:

```
<ion-icon [src]="myCustomIcon"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 3):

in Angular.json:

```
"assets":[
   {
      "glob":"**/*",
      "input":"src/assets",
      "output":"assets"
   },
   {
      "glob":"**/*.svg",
      "input":"node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
      "output":"./svg"
   },
   {
      "glob":"**/custom-*.svg",
      "input":"src/assets/icon_custom",
      "output":"./svg"
   }
]
```

And now start your custom svg icons whith "custom-..." in icon_custom (for example) folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use the custom icon SVG file in the ionic 5. No need to add anything like :

...
"assets": [
...
{
"glob": "**/*.svg",
"input": "src/assets/icon",
"output": "./svg"
},
...
]
...
use interfaces.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on ***Ionic 6 / Angular***

.html

```
<ion-icon [src]="sort" class="font-size-60"></ion-icon>
```

.ts

```
sort = 'assets/images/svgs/sort.svg';
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the accepted answer by TelmaC to work for me eventually but I had a lot of trouble because of a few gotchas that aren't well documented:

- Icons names with underscores **don't work** ; simply changing the filename (and icon name) from `ic_sharer` to `ic-sharer` suddenly fixed the issue for me.
- You need the angular.json copy bits in place as in her answer and if you have ionic serve running already you need to restart it after changing angular.json.
- If you want ionic's colouring and disabled states to work well you need to make sure there is no colour (fill or stroke) in the svg file - ideally no control of stroke-width either.

Answer (score -1):

For someone who is using font awesome type of icon fonts, you may just use `class="fa icon"`. For example:

```
<ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
  <ion-icon class="fa icon"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label >Inbox</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```

or if you are using your own icon set, you might use something like:

```
<ion-icon class="custom-icon icon-edit"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: You're not using `class="fa icon"` in your example??

Comment: Thanks for correction. I made my own icon set named `"my-icon"` as font-awesome is using `"fa"`.

Comment: Where is the font awesome icon in your example?

Answer (score -2):

Just implement "FormsModule" in your root module.

Answer (score -6):

You can just add your SVG files to the node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg Folder

Comment: This might technically work, but I would not recommend it. The node_modules folder is by default ignored by version control like git and that for a good reason. Or if you have to update or reinstall npm libs, you will lose your changes. 
General hint for the future: Try to avoid manipulating content that is managed by package managers to save yourself a lot of trouble.