# Ionic 5 / React: Use ion-icon to embed custom SVG

Tags: ionic-framework, svg, ionic5, ionic-react

I have a React app in Ionic 5 and I want to add some custom SVGs to it.

[This SO question is about Angular,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286018/custom-icons-with-ionic-5) but my question is about React.

My app folder structure looks like this:

- src

  - assets

    - listen.svg
    - SvgListen.tsx

Here is **SvgListen.tsx**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as ListenSvg } from './listen.svg';
import { IonIcon } from '@ionic/react';

const SvgListen = () => (
  <>
    <ListenSvg />
    <IonIcon src="./listen.svg" font-size="48px" />

  </>
);

export default SvgListen;
```

When testing the app in Chrome, I get this HTML:

```
<ion-icon src="./listen.svg" font-size="48px" role="img" class="ios hydrated"></ion-icon>
```

The `<ListenSvg />` that I imported is displayed correctly; however, the ion-icon is not displayed.  There is no error message, either.

I checked [this blog post](https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/01/Custom-SVG-icons-in-Ionic.html), but no luck with the approach outlined there, either.

How can I show a custom SVG using `<IonIcon>` in Ionic 5?

Comment: If an `img` tag with the same `src` doesn't work the problem is probably not with `ion-icon`. Check your build output for the correct location of the SVG file. I've never used react but quick googling suggests you have to `import` the SVG: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I updated the question based on your link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According do the [Create React App docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) you can import images to get their final path in the output bundle:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonIcon } from '@ionic/react';
import listenSvg from './listen.svg';

const SvgListen = () => (
  <IonIcon src={listenSvg} font-size="48px" />
);

export default SvgListen;
```